# Adding dynamic tabs in angular 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add a tab on a button click dynamically in angular 2.0. I am currently following this

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ud1x10xee7BmtUaSAA2R?p=preview)

It's asking for a parameter and I changed it to `TemplateRef<any>`. But I get error like

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 7 in `[ngFor #detail of details] in TabComponent@5:14 ("
        You have {{details.length}} details.
    </template>
    <template [ERROR ->]*ngFor="#detail of details" ui-pane [title]="detail.title">
        {{detail.text}}
        <br>
"): TabComponent@5:14
Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 7 in [ngFor #detail of details] in TabComponent@5:14 ("ave {{details.length}} details.
    </template>
    <template *ngFor="#detail of details" ui-pane [ERROR ->][title]="detail.title">
        {{detail.text}}
        <br>
"): TabComponent@5:50
Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 7 in [ngFor #detail of details] in TabComponent@5:14 ("details.
    </template>
    <template *ngFor="#detail of details" ui-pane [title]="detail.title">[ERROR ->]
        {{detail.text}}
        <br>
"): TabComponent@5:73
Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 7 in [ngFor #detail of details] in TabComponent@5:14 ("
        <br>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" [ERROR ->](click)="removeDetail(detail)">Remove</button>
    </template>
    <template ui-pane title='Summary"): TabComponent@9:28
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'template'. ("
        You have {{details.length}} details.
    </template>
    <template [ERROR ->]*ngFor="#detail of details" ui-pane [title]="detail.title">
        {{detail.text}}
        <br>
"): TabComponent@5:14
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "directives" section. ("
        You have {{details.length}} details.
    </template>
```

Please let me know is there anything wrong in passing `<any>` type to `TemplateRef` or anything needs to be changed here.

Any other code to dynamically add tab is also appreciated.

Comment: share the plunker link?

Comment: Did you try to replace # with let?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ud1x10xee7BmtUaSAA2R?p=preview. In the import changed to @angular/core and in the constructor changed templateRef to templateRef<any>

Comment: Replacing # with let worked fine. Great ! thank you.

Comment: Can you also please let me know how to replace add detail button as a plus marked button next to each tab, so that on click of plus button, a new tab gets added.